# C# Conditional Attribute: What about using directives?

Tags: c#, conditional-compilation, platform-specific

I am writing a c# application that currently uses

```
#if IOS
using Plugin.Firebase.iOS;
#else
using Plugin.Firebase.Android;
#endif
```

and then it uses it later on:

```
void SomeMethod(Events events) {
#if IOS
    events.AddiOS( _ => { // AddiOS is only present on the IOS version of plugin library
        // some IOS specific code
    };
#else
    events.AddAndroid( _ => { // AddAndroid is only present on the Android version of plugin library
        // some Android specific code
    };
#endif
}
```

I just learned about conditional attributes. They seems super powerful and easier to use.

However, when I refactor the call to AddiOS() into its own conditional method using

```
[Conditional("IOS")]
```

it gives a compiler error since it can't find Plugin.Firebase.iOS anymore. If I remove the #if for the using directives, I get compilation errors.

Is there a way to attach using directives to conditional methods somehow? A google search didn't turn anything up, but I wasn't too sure what to search for.

Just to add: I can get conditional methods working when they don't depend on packages that need to be imported using #if as well.

Comment: I haven't used these target compilation preprocessors yet, so I have to ask, what is it exactly that prevents you from having both using directives? If they are unused at compile time due to preprocessor logic they will not get compiled. Is it a namespace collision?

Comment: _"Is there a way to attach using directives to conditional methods somehow?"_ - Sort-of: you can now define global `using` statements in `.csproj` files, which means you can use MSBuild properties and environment-variables (and C# preprocessor symbols) - this can also be used to include or exclude entire `.cs` files too.

Comment: ...that said, _don't try to be too smart_ and use every esoteric compiler feature out there - the preprocessor `#if` is the best tool for the job _because it's the simplest_ - keep it that way.